# How pass js Map into Spring controller

Tags: javascript, json, spring-boot

I have a map formed in js script on client side. I need to pass this map into Spring Controller POST method. I tried many ways, but they don't work.

Map has following structure `Map<String, List<String>>` :
`{"first question":[["text"]],"second question":[["1","2","3"]]}`

I need to get it in my Controller method. I tried to pass it by fetchAPI and Ajax. With JSON.stringify(data) and without, as array. But I don't datas in Controller.  If I use @RequestBody, i get error "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported".

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/newQue")
    public String createQue(@RequestBody Map<String, List<String>> data){

        data.values().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If I use @RequestParam or @ModelAttribute, i don't get data, i get only csrf code. If need additional information, I provide.

Comment: you have double [] for your list, it should be singular

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain in more derail?

Comment: Map<String, List<String>> is equal to Json {"first question":["text"],"second question":["1","2","3"]} , notice the difference with what you have

Comment: I think, my problem isn't in it. I think that my problem is wrong sending parameters on server, because I can't get anything, even simple String, using method described in question.